# SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect

Tags: php, sql-server

here is my error`

> **Warning**:  odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '123'., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in **C:\xampp\htdocs\Estadias\api\MODELS\connection_sql_server.php** on line **19**
>   Error [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '123'.

the query:

```
 select todos.matricula,u.constrasenia, todos.nombres,todos.paterno,t.id ,t.description 
from usuarios u join typeofuser t on u.tipo = t.id 
join (select matricula,nombres, paterno from Alumnos union select id as 
id, numbres, paterno from tutores union select id as id, nombre, paterno   
from asesor_empresarial) todos on todos.matricula = u.id where u.id = 
'12312' and u.constrasenia = '123';
```

here my code.

```
$user= $_POST['usr_id'];
$pswd=$_POST['usr_psw'];
if (isset($user) && isset($pswd))
{

$connection = new SqlServerConnection();
try
{
    $query = sprintf('select todos.matricula,u.constrasenia,           
    todos.nombres,todos.paterno,t.id ,t.description from usuarios u 
    join typeofuser t on u.tipo = t.id join (select matricula,nombres,
    paterno from Alumnos union select id as id, numbres, paterno 
    from tutores union select id as id, nombre, paterno 
    from asesor_empresarial) todos on todos.matricula = u.id where u.id =
    \''.$user.'\' and u.constrasenia = \''.$pswd."';");

    echo $query;

    $data=$connection->execute_query($query);

    odbc_result($data, 'matricula');
    odbc_result($data, 'constrasenia');
    odbc_result($data, 'nombres');
    odbc_result($data, 'paterno');
    odbc_result($data, 'id');
    odbc_result($data, 'description');

    if (odbc_result($data, 'matricula')=='' && odbc_result($data, 'constrasenia')=='') {

            echo $result='{"status" : 1 , "Descrition" : "User Not Found" }';
                    die;
    }
    $u = new User(odbc_result($data, 'id'),odbc_result($data, 'constrasenia'));
    echo '
        { "status" : "0" ,
             "User":
             {
                "userID" : "'.$u->get_id().'",
                "nombre" : "'.$nombre.'",
                "paterno" : "'.$paterno.'",
                "imagen" : "'.$img.'",
                "UserType" : 
                                {
                                    "ID" : "'.$u->get_user_type()->get_id_type().'",
                                    "Description" : "'.$u->get_user_type()->get_description().'"
                                },
                "token" : "'.generate_token($user).'"                   
             } 
        }';
}
finally
{
    $connection->close();
}
```

Comment: Dude your code is an open door to SQL injection. you need to sanitise `$user` and `$pswd` before you concatenate it in your SQL. And can you please translate the error from Spanish to English as this website is in English. please.

Comment: This query would execute successfully if it was passed directly to SQL Server, so check what `execute_query` actually does. Maybe it mangles the query. Also, what Fabrice said: do not use text replacement, use parameters. If you're using ODBC, see [`odbc_execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php). And read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).